What network am I connected to and what is Air OS?
I recently joined a dedicated network and the network has been really slow. I went to check if there are other devices on the network and this is the page that comes up for the router for the dns server at 192.168.3.1.

I've never heard of it and nothing shows in google for the searches except for some links to this reddit page https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubiquiti/.
If I go to 192.168.1.1 it says I'm connected to Starlink. Uh, what? What's going on here?
Also, the network type keeps finding it as a private network, not public.
In the network adapters I have 3 virtual network adapters.
Local Area Connection* 8
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Status: not operational

Local Area Connection* 10
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Status: not operational

WiFi
*Brand Network Adapter
Status: operational
Connectivity IP4/IP6: Connected to Internet / Connected to unknown network

Do I need to be concerned?
Can I delete the virtual adapters?
If I have two ip addresses, how do I find the router home page?


What network am I connected to and what is Air OS?

It doesn't say anything about the network you're on. "airOS" is the name of the firmware used in Ubiquiti's "airMAX" series of Wi-Fi products – such as their NanoStation point-to-point wireless bridges, which are commonly used either to link two buildings a few kilometers across, or to link customers to a wireless-ISP antenna on some tower.
Indeed the first result for "air OS" in Google is a link to its manual. The screenshot you have is airOS version 5.x/6.x, which would've been used in NanoStation M5 and similar 'Wireless-N' products (not the newer 'AC' ones which have a much fancier 8.x).
Though they're called bridges, they do have full "gateway/router" functionality as well, if enabled through the configuration pages (e.g. for WISP customers, the 'client' units could be in router mode instead of needing a dedicated router). That's what you're seeing at 192.168.3.1.
(Because it's the 5.x/6.x branch of airOS, it could've also been used in a few other kinds of products, such as now-obsolete 'PicoStation' outdoor Wi-Fi access points, or 'Bullet' long-range wireless bridges that connect to a dedicated "grid antenna" on the roof – the coax connecting it to the antenna literally being a "Wi-Fi cable" – but the medium-range bridges are by far the most likely ones.)


If I go to 192.168.1.1 it says I'm connected to Starlink. Uh, what? What's going on here?

The device running airOS is connected to a Starlink gateway. Both are working as routers, so two local subnets are created; one 192.168.3.x between you and the airOS router, and one 192.168.1.x between the airOS router and the Starlink router.
It's similar to what you would get if you bought two home wifi routers and chained them (ISP → "WAN" of wifi router A → its "LAN" connected to "WAN" of wifi router B).

If I have two ip addresses, how do I find the router home page?

Both are 'the' router home page, because there are two routers along the path.
But generally speaking, your computer's "Default gateway" parameter (as seen in ipconfig) is always going to show you the IP address of the router that is closest to you.
The "DNS server" parameter doesn't always work for that (there isn't a strong relationship between routers and DNS servers, they could be different devices), but the "Default gateway" parameter is literally the address of the router your computer is using – 'gateway' being an older term for 'router' in this case.
When there are multiple routers, though, you need to use "traceroute"-like tools such as the Windows tracert or WinMTR to see addresses of the routers/gateways beyond the first one. But keep in mind that they don't necessarily have a home page – at least not one that you can access.

Do I need to be concerned?

No. Windows creates the "Wi-Fi Direct" virtual adapters as soon as the physical Wi-Fi adapter is installed, and they usually sit unused.
(I don't think I've ever seen actual use of Wi-Fi Direct in practice… at least not on PCs. But if I remember correctly, Windows also makes use of the WiDi virtual adapter for its "Wireless hotspot" feature, because it allows the same adapter to be simultaneously an AP/hotspot and a client to some other Wi-Fi network.)
